# Use of stubRoutine, StubAssembler classes

Tags: jvm

I wanted to know, 
1. Use of above classes and how does it used. 
2. Whether it is used in both c1 and c2 compiler or it is only used in one of the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

*VM Stubs* are reusable functions in a platform-specific assembly dynamically gererated at VM startup.

Comments at [`StubRoutines.hpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c1374141598c/src/share/vm/runtime/stubRoutines.hpp#l50) answer your questions:

```
// StubRoutines provides entry points to assembly routines used by
// compiled code and the run-time system. Platform-specific entry
// points are defined in the platform-specific inner class.
```

These entry points are shared between VM, interpreter and both compilers. Example functions are:

- arraycopy
- atomic_cmpxchg
- throw_NullPointerException, throw_StackOverflowError
- encryptAES, decryptAES
- sin, cos, log, exp
- etc.

[`StubAssembler`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c1374141598c/src/share/vm/c1/c1_MacroAssembler.hpp#l67) is a macroassembler used to generate some C1-specific stubs for throwing and catching exceptions, for refilling TLAB, for handling slow cases of monitorenter, checkcast etc.

Comment: I have written small java code and used Arrays.copyOf() function. Then I dumped the compiler log using printcompilation flag. But the arraycopy machine code dump and the JVM_arraycopy(dumped using objdump of libjvm.so) does not match.  But i could see a "compile_kind='c2n'" output then a java.lang.System::arraycopy (native)   (static) print. I wanted to know why the machine code using objdump and in the log file output do not match?

Comment: @hareeshr `objdump` gives you static version embedded in the binary, but the stubs used by compilers are *generated dynamically* at run-time.

Comment: Thanks . I went through the code and found the intrinsic implementation of arraycopy in c1(lir_arraycopy), and it calls the do_call and I stuck there. I could not find where the actual implementation is ?.

Comment: @hareeshr In [stubGenerator_<arch>.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c1374141598c/src/cpu/x86/vm/stubGenerator_x86_64.cpp#l2806)